# Reset/Cancel button not working on error in MVC 4 using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that basically captures user information to be saved to the Database. There is a `username` field and it has to be `unique` for each user. The problem I am facing is that on error, when a duplicate user name is entered, the validation is firing and the `field-validation-error` class is applied on the textbox. But there are `cancel` and `reset` buttons on the page, which is not functioning as expected. On click of the buttons, nothing is happening any further, but as per the code, it should redirect to another form. I am trying to capture the method through Tempdata. Need help.

Comment: Post the code..nobody can help you with out the codes

Comment: _"but as per the code"_? What code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Remote Validation of MVC** this will Resolve your issue . 
As you type your name it will check in database and update Jsonresult to client side and show Message .